# Can a state machine diagram be drawn for a singleton?

Tags: uml

I have a singleton class that performs a number of tasks:

- Registers a listener to receive location updates.
- Unregisters listener.
- Triggers a API call if the listener method gets called.

I want to draw a state machine diagram for the class but was wondering whether it is correct to do so for a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should a singleton instance be any different from any other instance? The singleton pattern simply makes the constructor private so there can only be one instance, obtained through a `getInstance()` operation.

You should consider modeling the class in UML as an "active class" to declare that the class has autonomous behavior that "never" ends. As explained in the UML 2.5 spec:

> An active object is an object that, as a direct consequence of its creation, commences to execute its classifierBehavior, and does not cease until either the complete Behavior is executed or the object is terminated by some external object. (This is sometimes referred to as “the object having its own thread of control.”) The points at which an active object responds to communications from other objects is determined solely by the Behavior of the active object and not by the invoking object. If the classifierBehavior of an active object completes, the object is terminated.

Comment: What would then be a "not active object"? All classes instantiate and exist until they terminate the one or other way. Sounds like once again another OMG blurb :-/

Comment: An inactive object is one where the meta-property `isActive` is false for a class. An inactive object only gets CPU time when another objects invokes it. In contrast, an active object starts running in its own thread as soon as it is created. In that thread the object can run a state machine and handle signals.

Comment: The paragraph about _Active class behaviors_ above confused me completely. This UML specification is of poor quality.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do that. The one ain't got to do anything with the other. Singleton means, that there is just a single instance. Now the state machine can respect or ignore this fact depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify would the diagram have a end state? as the singleton never gets destroyed.

Comment: If there is no end state you don't need that symbol. But a singleton can well be destroyed. It has just a single instance (which might die at a time).You are talking about an infinite state machine.